# Login/signup flow as a modal

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to use React Navigation to control the flow of an app. When the app opens, it loads a stack navigator that has two screens: Home (my app's main screen) and Access (a component which is another stack navigator that starts with a login page). This is my `App.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import Access from './screens/access/index';
import Home from './screens/Home';

const Root = createAppContainer(createStackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: Home },
  Access: { screen: Access }
}, {
  headerMode: 'none',
  mode: 'modal'
}));

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Root />
    );
  }
}
```

In my Home screen, I check if the user is logged in (in the constructor), and if they aren't I want to show the Access screen as a modal. Obviously I could trigger `this.props.navigation.navigate({ routeName: 'Access' })` from the constructor but I want to avoid the animation. I thought in the constructor of `./screens/Home` I'd try:

```
const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
  index: 1,
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Home' }),
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Access' }),
  ],
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

Somehow this fails because `Error: There is no route defined for key Home. Must be one of: 'Login','Password','Signup'`. This is certainly referring to the routes in the stack navigator defined in `./screens/access/index`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import Login from './Login';
import Password from './Password';
import Signup from './Signup';

const Access = createStackNavigator({
  Login: { screen: Login },
  Password: { screen: Password },
  Signup: { screen: Signup }
}, {
  headerMode: 'none'
});
export default createAppContainer(Access);
```

However, I'm not sure why it believes that those are the routes when I call `this.props.navigation.dispatch` within `./screens/Home`.

Finally, on a separate issue, I want to be able to dismiss the modal from the Access screens. On the first screen of that stack (Login), I can trigger  `this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.back())` to dismiss the modal. However, if Login pushes Signup over it, that just goes back to Login (instead of dismissing the modal). How can I achieve that?